# Angular JS + Spring MVC: Getting a 406 while trying to download a generated file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm trying to download a file that was generated from the database base64 `String` field. I see that file is created successfully but download fails...

This is my Spring MVC controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Response download(@RequestBody DocumentCaseFile documentCaseFile) throws ServiceLogicException {
        return documentCaseFileService.prepareFile(documentCaseFile);
    }
```

Here is the service method:

```
@Override
    public Response prepareFile(DocumentCaseFile documentCaseFile) throws ServiceLogicException {
        final String contents = documentCaseFile.getContent();
        final String pathAndFileName = "files/" + documentCaseFile.getFilename();
        File file = new File(pathAndFileName);
        byte[] decodedImg = Base64.getDecoder().decode(contents.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Path destinationFile = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.write(destinationFile, decodedImg);
            file = destinationFile.getFileName().toFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            file = null;
        }
        return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
                .build();
    }
```

And here is the frontend part for the download function:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(documentCaseFile) {
       $http.post(webserviceUrl + documentCaseFileDownload, documentCaseFile, {
         headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
         }
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('file download response');
            console.log(response);
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.error('file download error');
            console.log(response);
         });
```

};

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` was causing the problem in the controller, I had to remove it to make the error go away:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when you have response.getOutputStream(), you can write anything there. You can pass this output stream as a place to put generated PDF to your generator. Also, if you know what file type you are sending, you can set

response.setContentType("application/pdf");

and you are use into you angular code, you need to change it with fie type

```
headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
     }
```